# Eclipse Neon.2 con Vaadin 7.7 y Maven. (Error 404 not found)

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, jboss, vaadin

Queria consultarles si alguien tuvo el mismo problema y como lo soluciono.

Cuando hago un proyecto nuevo con **Eclipse de Vaadin 7 Maven**, lo corro en **Jboss 7.0** y da un error: *404 not found*, en cambio si inicio el proyecto **vaadin con Ivy** funciona correctamente.

Tambien si lo pruebo con Jetty, wildfly 8,9,10 funciona correctamente pero para un proyecto necesito usar Jboss 7.0 unicamente.

¿Alguna idea?

Gracias de antemano!

Comment: ¿La URL a la que accedes en ambos casos es la misma? ¿Puedes comparar los web.xml generados?

Comment: Hola gracias por tu respuesta.
Si, la url es la misma en todos los casos [http://localhost:8080/MiAplicacion/]

Cuando genero un proyecto Vaadin 7 Maven, no genera los web.xml, genera un pom.xml.

Saludos y gracias

Comment: yo creo que en la parte superior de tu pom tienes `<packagin>pom</packaging>` y ese podria ser el error. Para saberlo tendrias que agregar la version minima de tu `pom.xml`